# MP3 loading using librosa return empty data when start_time metadata is 0

Tags: python, audio, mp3, loading, librosa

I have a dataset of thousands of bird chirps audios (mp3) and I try to load them using `librosa.load()`

MP3 files are loaded but, most of the time, resulting data is an empty *np.ndarray* instead of a *np.ndarray* filled with *floats*

Using `pydub.utils.mediainfo()` I wanted to compare MP3 metadata. This function return information such as *sampling_rate*, *codec*, *duration*, *bitrate*, *start_time*, ...

I found out that *start_time* information was the explanation of failed loadings. Indeed, every file where *start_time* **is 0** are not loaded correctly. At the contrary every file where *start_time* **is over 0** are loaded correctly.

I have no problem listening every single MP3 file using VLC audio player.

Is there anything that can explain this behavior? Is there any solution to make these loadings succeed?

Comment: What happens when start_time is a very small, but non-zero value. LIke 0.1, 0.01 etc? If you can provide a minimum failing example, then this is probably something you should file as a bug with librosa. Along with other info to reproduce, like the versions of relevant libraries, OS etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same very specific error. The error message I was getting was "Input signal length=0 is too small to resample from 48000->22050", which was because librosa was loading empty arrays in the same circumstances as you mention.

My workaround for it was to specify a duration parameter, in this case I set it to the full length of the file:

```
dur = pydub.utils.mediainfo(filepath)["duration"]

data, sr = librosa.load(filepath,  duration = math.floor(float(dur)))
```

This solved the empty arrays for me